# Pandas similarity function rowwise best performance

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, text-mining

I would like to compare two Texts with limited character rowwise in a pandas DataFrame. Therefore, I use the following function:

```
def cos_tf_idf(s):
    #s is the DataFrame with the text columns 'ds1_bio' and 'ds2_bio'
    #Tokenize words
    s['v1'] = [word_tokenize(unicode(w)) for w in s['ds1_bio'].values]
    s['v2'] = [word_tokenize(unicode(w)) for w in s['ds2_bio'].values]
    #Create set of word
    s['v'] = [Set(x[0] + x[1]) for x in s[['v1', 'v2']].itertuples(index=False)]
    #Count each word in sentence
    s['count1'] = [Counter(x[0]) for x in s[['v1', 'v']].itertuples(index=False)]
    s['count2'] = [Counter(x[0]) for x in s[['v2', 'v']].itertuples(index=False)]
    #calculated normalized TF-IDF scheme: (Number of Word occured in Sentence/Total Number of Words in Sentence) * log(# of Documents/# of Word occurs in all sentences)
    s['vec1_normalized'] = [[float(x[0][w]) / float(len(x[2])) * math.log1p(2 / float(x[0][w] + x[3][w])) for w in x[1]]
                            for x in s[['count1', 'v', 'v1', 'count2']].itertuples(index=False)]
    s['vec2_normalized'] = [[float(x[0][w]) / float(len(x[2])) * math.log1p(2 / float(x[0][w] + x[3][w])) for w in x[1]]
                            for x in s[['count2', 'v', 'v2', 'count1']].itertuples(index=False)]
    #Calculate Cosine Sim of TF-IDF
    s['oben_TF'] = [sum([w[0] * w[1] for w in zip(x[0], x[1])]) for x in s[['vec1_normalized', 'vec2_normalized']].itertuples(index=False)]
    s['unten1_TF'] = [sum([l ** 2 for l in x[0]]) ** 0.5 for x in s[['vec1_normalized']].itertuples(index=False)]
    s['unten2_TF'] = [sum([l ** 2 for l in x[0]]) ** 0.5 for x in s[['vec2_normalized']].itertuples(index=False)]
    s['bio_syntact_similarity'] = [x[0] / (x[1] * x[2]) for x in s[['oben_TF', 'unten1_TF', 'unten2_TF']].itertuples(index=False)]
    return s.drop(['v1','v2','v','count1','count2','vec1_normalized','vec2_normalized','oben_TF','unten1_TF','unten2_TF'],axis=1)
```

Basically, the function should return the Cosine Similarity on TF-IDF weighted arrays between the two texts. However, if I run the code on a Dataset with 90000 rows it takes 2 minutes,  but I want to use it on millions of rows.

Are there any options for optimization?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using pre-built functions in scikit-learn or scipy?

Comment: Yes, don't use `pandas.DataFrames`with `dtypes` that are `object`, use a `numpy.ndarray` with an appropriate numeric `dtype`, and use the optimized, built-in routines in `scipy` and `sklearn`. Your entire approach has pretty much lost all hope of being fast.

Comment: I am new to pandas at all. Do you have a concrete example or link to a documentation?

Comment: Let me put it this way, I've never, *ever* used `pandas.DataFrames` to accomplish what you are doing. Rather, I save my docs as strings in a vanilla `list`, but transform that into a sparse-matrix using an sklearn [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer)`, and then for cosine similarity, you can use vectorized routines in scipy...

Comment: Also, `sklearn` has excellent documentation and user-guides. I suggest perusing [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction). Happy coding!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Surprised no one has mentioned taking this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/